# IEnumerable<> becomes null while progressing in the code

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have written a very simple windows application using .Net Core which produces an IEnumerable with 1000 records.
In the following code which is shown as an example, my IEnumerable return the correct records while the second line of code return null.

```cs
IEnumerable<test> myList = null; 
myList     = from item in myTable select ....();        
var result = myList.ToList();  //myList has 1000 records                  
int total  = myList.Count(); //myList is null
```

I don't understand why `myList` is not persisted and is changed to `null`. It looks like it is flushed after being used once.

---

Please see the real code below:

```cs
using var dbContextTransation = _context.Database.BeginTransaction();
try
{
    IEnumerable<BuoyLocation> positionList = null; 
    var allPosition = csvReader.GetRecords<MyFormat>();
    
    positionList =
        from location in allPosition
        select new Location()
        {                                              
            LocationDateTime = location.Fecha.Add(new TimeSpan( Convert.ToInt32( location.Hora.Left(2) ), Convert.ToInt32( location.Hora.Right(2) ), 0 ) ),                                               
            Latitude         = location.Latitud,
            Longitude        = location.Longitud
        };  
    
    var result = positionList.ToList();//List has 1000 records 
    int total = positionList.Count(); //List is null
        
    ....
    dbContextTransation.Commit();
//  _context.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Committed " + DateTime.Now);
    
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    dbContextTransation.Rollback();
    LogService.LogWrite(textFile, "ERR:" + ex.Message + " ->" + ex.InnerException.Message);                        
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Please post your **actual** code so we can run it ourselves.

Comment: IEnumerable is just an instruction set for how to enumerate. Rather than using the IEnumerable to get the count rather use result.Count as this is a static field on the List<T> type rather than forcing another enumeration through the IEnumerable.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal There is nothing wrong with using IEnumerable in this case, but the code posted is obviously missing the actual problem.

Comment: @Neil well, iterating twice isn't needed, since the Count property on the list is already available. But other than that I agree with you on missing the problematic code.

Comment: @TheEvilMetal: `Count` is not a static field but a property. However, you're right that OP should use that because otherwise the "query" `myList`(which is not a list) must be enumerated again and again to determine the count. So it's much better to use `int total = result.Count;`.

Comment: Works on my internet: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GQ5EGH

Comment: @SylvainC how do you verify this behavior? Do you notice this while debugging the code?

Comment: `positionList` can't be null. How do you know that?

Comment: Yes I am just debugging, doing step by step and on int total = positionList.Count; it is null.

Comment: @SylvainC. - `null` or `0`? It doesn't seem very likely that it's `null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't mention you are using CsvHelper.

As stated here:
https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/

> "The GetRecords method will return an IEnumerable that will
> yield records. What this means is that only a single record is
> returned at a time as you iterate the records. That also means that
> only a small portion of the file is read into memory. Be careful
> though. If you do anything that executes a LINQ projection, such as
> calling .ToList(), the entire file will be read into memory. CsvReader
> is forward only, so if you want to run any LINQ queries against your
> data, you'll have to pull the whole file into memory. Just know that
> is what you're doing."

The CSVReader is using a StreamReader, which isn't reset between your two calls. Since you are already reading the entire file into a list by calling ToList, just use the result variable for whatever you are trying to do.

If you only want to know the count, and do nothing with the results, then calling Count() on your myList variable should work just fine.

If, for some reason, you still want to count the initial variable, you should reset your stream. This is also mentioned in the documentation of CsvHelper:

https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/prerequisites/streams/

Example:

```
using (var stream = new File.OpenRead("path\\to\\file"))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{   
    // Read file content.
    var content = reader.ReadToEnd();

    // Go back to beginning of the stream.
    stream.Position = 0;

    // Read file content again.
    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: Probably a stupid question but it is  `allPosition ` which is populated by the GetRecords method not the  `positionList ` that I am trying to use. Does  `positionList ` inherit from  `allPosition `?